# Need help getting a specific key's post meta data, from all posts in a specific post type, into a comma seperated string variable

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, metadata

Wordpress:
Ok so I have a post type category called wineries and for each winery post there is a custom field called address in which each wineries' address is listed. I would like to make a full page google map with all of these wineries marked. In order to do that I need to take all of the address custom field data from every post and put it into one comma separated string variable in order to pass it to my google map. I have fiddled around with it for a while and figured I should get some help. Here is what I have came up with so far. I was able to echo all of the addresses onto the page using a foreach statement, but that doesn't really do me any good

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'   => 'wineries',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids'
    )
);

foreach($posts as $p){

    $ads = get_post_meta($p,"address",true);
    echo $ads; echo',';
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if that worked for you. Otherwise people won't be interested in answering questions of yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '';
foreach($posts as $p){
    $ads = get_post_meta($p,"address",true);
    if($ads)
       $str .= $ads.',';
  }
$str = substr($str,0,-1);
```

Pass this string,$str to Your google map.